# Unreal Engine Linux Support

Tags: unreal-4, linux, build-process

I use multiple game Engines, but havn't used Unreal engine for quite a while, Now with the recent changes in Unreal Engine there are quite some interesting features which would be interesting to use in games.

**However** I also recently heard that UE4 recently dropped build support for Linux. 
So my main 2 questions are
1. Did UE4 truly drop Linux build support?
and if so
2. Is there a way to get Linux build support in the latest version of UE4?

I can check the first question myself but due to the large engine size and my slow network connection this would take very long, so I figured it would save a lot of time if someone who already has the newest version installed knew the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [questions about software support / requirements are generally not considered on-topic here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2399/33287).

Answer (score 1):

The Unreal Engine supports Linux OS. The official UE4 documentation contains a section that describes the [installation procedure for Linux OS.](https://rhycesmith.com/2019/05/02/compiling-unreal-engine-4-from-source/)